# How to edit the self.TeamScore value in my code

Tags: python, list, class

I am trying to make a leaderboard for a school tournament. I began asking the user to input some team names and how many members in the team. Now i want to be able to ask the user; 'who won the game?' and then adjust that teams score by 1.

How can i change a teams score based on the users input?

```
class AllTeams:
  def __init__(self, TeamNum, TeamName, TeamMembers,    TeamScore):
    self.TeamNum = TeamNum
    self.TeamName = TeamName
    self.TeamMembers = TeamMembers
    self.TeamScore = TeamScore

  def __repr__(self):
    return f'Team Number: {self.TeamNum} |-| Team Name: {self.TeamName} |-| Member Count: {self.TeamMembers} |-| Team Score: {self.TeamScore}'

#teams = [AllTeams(i+1, "N/A", 0) for i in range(20)]
teams = []

TeamCounter=int(input('How many Teams will be in the tournament? '))

print('')
for i in range(TeamCounter):
    NameOfTeam=input(f'Please Enter Team {i+1} Name: ')
    MemberCount=input('How Many Members in Team? ')
    print('')
    teams.append( AllTeams( i+1, NameOfTeam, MemberCount, 0) )

def score():
    for t in teams:
    print(t)

    GameWinner=input('Which Team Won the Event? ')

    #change team score by 1
```

Comment: How are you calling these functions?

Comment: which? @BrokenBenchmark

Comment: All of them. The code also doesn't look indented quite right. I'd like to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: the naming of `AllTeams` is strange, should be just `Team`. Then : do you to ask once for a winner then program stop , or another way ?

Comment: all of the code works, for creating team names and member counts. however i want to create a seperate function to add scores to the teams when they win an event

Comment: Loop through `teams` to find the one whose `TeamNum` or `TeamName` matches `GameWinner` and increment that team's `TeamScore`.

Comment: there will be lets say 20 events, so 20 winners, 20 points to be given out. i want to ask the user who won the event. then add the points to that team and form a leaderboard

Comment: your class is a barrier between you and solution. if you declare all its members as global variables, you can easily add, delete or modify their values.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp this sounds like what i am wanting, but i have no idea on how to do this

Comment: How to do this @marmeladze?

Comment: @robbie2301 sth like https://replit.com/@marmeladze1/StaleDisguisedQbasic#main.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate on the teams to find the one with the good name to update hi score

```
def score(teams):
    winner = input('Which Team Won the Event? ')
    for team in teams:
        if team.name == winner:
            team.add_victory()
            break
```

Then a few better naming and the class becomes

```
class Team:
    def __init__(self, num, name, size, score):
        self.num = num
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.score = score

    def add_victory(self):
        self.score += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Team Number: {self.num} |-| Team Name: {self.name} |-| Member Count: {self.size} |-| Team Score: {self.score}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking through your direction here, I think it helps to clear up some misunderstandings on classes(or what I and others are perceiving as misunderstandings).

In short, a class is an object, which is like a representation of a thing. In your case a `Team` is a thing. It has a count of members, a name, a number, etc. So your class should be named "Team" not "AllTeams".

In that same vein, a `Game` is a thing. It has attributes like a home team, an away team, a date on which it was played, a score for the home and away team, a venue, etc. And it may have a method like "WhoWon()" that uses the score to determine whether the home team or away team won.

Thinking through that it makes sense that a score is an attribute of a game, not a team, since it's likely a team will play multiple games during the tournament and will have a distinct score for each game played. That would be a pain to track inside a `Team`.

So, consider something like:

```
class Team:

    #setting this outside of a method allows us to get it or set it outside of the class in the main code like a "global" for the class.
    TeamName = ''

    def __init__(self, TeamNum, TeamName, TeamMembers):
        self.TeamNum = TeamNum
        self.TeamName = TeamName
        self.TeamMembers = TeamMembers

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Team Number: {self.TeamNum} |-| Team Name: {self.TeamName} |-| Member Count: {self.TeamMembers} |-| Team Score: {self.TeamScore}'

class Game:
    
    def __init__(self, game_number, home_team, away_team, home_team_score, away_team_score):
        self.home_team = home_team
        self.away_team = away_team
        self.home_team_score = home_team_score
        self.away_team_score = away_team_score

    #a class method that returns the winner based on the scores
    def winner(self):
        if self.home_team_score > self.away_team_score:
            return self.home_team
        else:
            return self.away_team

#instead of lists, use dictionaries so you can refer to a game by its number, or a team by its name without having to jump through hoops. 
games={}
teams = {}

TeamCounter=int(input('How many Teams will be in the tournament? '))

print('')
for i in range(TeamCounter):
    NameOfTeam=input(f'Please Enter Team {i+1} Name: ')
    MemberCount=input('How Many Members in Team? ')
    print('')
    #Add to the teams dictionary.
    teams[NameOfTeam] = Team( i+1, NameOfTeam, MemberCount) 


#Lets collect info about the games in the tourny:
GameCounter=int(input("How many games are in the tournament?"))
for i in range(GameCounter):
    home_team = input("what was the name of the home team?")
    home_team_score = input("what was their score?")
    away_team = input("what was the name of the away team?")
    away_team_score = input("what was their score?")

    #create the game object
    this_game = Game(i, teams[home_team], teams[away_team], home_team_score, away_team_score)

    #Once we have this one game made we can see who won. Note that we call the method `winner()` for `this_game` object which returns a `Team` object for which we can get it's attribute `TeamName`: 
    print("It looks like "+this_game.winner().TeamName+" won the game!")
```

There's a million ways to pull this off, but I feel like this will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: this is very clear and easy to work with compared to what i had. how would i implement a leaderboard into this code?

Comment: Leaderboard feels like you need more information to figure out. When I think of a tournament I think of the order games were played and the parent/child relationship between games (which maybe you could figure out on the fly by when they were played and who played them, but it would be nice to store in the game class). If you have a parent/child relationship (like if you had `child_game` as an attribute in your `game` class) you could recursively  traverse your `games` dictionary to build the leadersboard on the fly (via a function) pretty easily.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this lol. i am using this code at the moment and am struggling to add a printable leaderboard

Comment: I guess a simple leaderboard (just like "top 10 teams" would be simple. You could iterate `for game in games:` and keep track of the winning team for each game. `leaderboard[game.winner] += 1` (or what have you) and then, once done, sort that dict by value and print out the list? I know how frustrating this stuff is when you get started. You'll have your head wrapped around this stuff soon. I always tell myself the pain and frustration I feel is what it feels like to learn :). If you are getting stuck with a particular issue, feel free to create a new question and folks can jump in to help.